# Difining the meaning of club

Tags: number-theory

If a club b = $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$
What is ( (3 club 4) club 12)?

I don't know what's the meaning of the word club. Any hint about it is what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know the meaning of the word. You can call it plolyphant if you want.to. You only need to apply the rule that $$a\text{ club } b = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

meaning that, for example, $$1\text{ club } 2 = \sqrt{1^2 + 2^2} = \sqrt{5}$$

So in order to calculate $$((3\text{ club } 4)\text{ club }12),$$

you first need to calculate $3\text{ club }4$, then proceed from there.

Comment: Wow.. I didnt know that this question is very easy! Thanks for the hint..

Comment: So the answer is 13. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @StephenMark Yup, the answer is $13$. Feel free to accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a printing error, for $\clubsuit$ which is just used as an arbitrary operation (think of it as a function).

Instead of $f(a,b)$ you write $a \clubsuit b$ where

$$a \clubsuit b = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$

So $$((3\clubsuit4)\clubsuit12) = \sqrt{(\sqrt{3^2+4^2})^2+12^2}$$